# Visual Editor for Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, ide

i am new to Eclipse IDE.

Please help me in installing Visual Editor.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recommend to use WindowBuilder instead of VE. See http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/installation/index.html

Comment: The previous answer is only partially correct. From Eclipse Indigo (v3.7) onwards, the WindowBuilder toolkit is already included in the Eclipse IDE and as such replaces the previous Visual Editor project that was used up to and including Eclipse Helios (v3.6). The WindowBuilder code was bought by Google and donated to the Eclipse IDE community.